# How do you create a WeldJoint in box2d to attach two bodies together?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently trying to attach a circle body on top of a rectangle body so that it is like a matchstick, I created the definitions and stuff, but the bodies move separately the rectangle body moves but the circlebody just stays still, it doesn't move as one body.

here is the code

```
/****************************************CREATING THE FIRST BODY (RECTANGLE BODY) ***********/
    rectangleBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    rectangleBodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    rectangleBodyDef.position.set(-10,2);
    rectangleBody = world.createBody(rectangleBodyDef);
    rectangleBodyShape = new PolygonShape();
    rectangleBodyShape.setAsBox(2f, 0.75f);
    rectangleBodyFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    rectangleBodyFixtureDef.shape = rectangleBodyShape;
    rectangleBodyFixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
    rectangleBody.createFixture(rectangleBodyFixtureDef);
    rectangleBody.setUserData(effect);

    /***************************************CREATING THE SECOND BODY (CIRCLE BODY) ************/
    circleBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    circleBodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    circleBodyDef.position.set(-7,2);
    circleBody = world.createBody(circleBodyDef);
    circleShape = new CircleShape();
    circleShape.setRadius(0.75f);
    circleFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    circleFixtureDef.shape = circleShape;
    circleFixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
    circleBody.createFixture(circleFixtureDef);

    /***********************************WELD JOINT*********************************************/
    weldJointDef = new WeldJointDef();
    weldJointDef.bodyA = rectangleBody;
    weldJointDef.bodyB = circleBody;
    weldJointDef.type =JointType.WeldJoint;
    weldJointDef.collideConnected = true;
    weldJointDef.localAnchorA.set(1, 0);
    weldJointDef.localAnchorB.set(-2,0);
    world.createJoint(weldJointDef);
```

Comment: I already answered you how to have both the rectangle and the circle as 2 fixtures of one single body, and thus moving together http://stackoverflow.com/a/21148436/1895303

Comment: yeh and i did it this is for a weldjoint now learning how to do it

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434188/fixing-two-box2d-bodies-together-securely